# I am looking for an C# implementation om AES-256 in CTR-mode

Tags: c#, aes

I've been searching the internet for an implementation of AES-256 in CTR-mode, in C#.
In the RijndaelManaged-class where you find in .Net-framework, you find some supported modes but not CTR. I read something about using ECB-mode, and XOR the plain-text.

Does anyone have information how to implement the AES-256 in CTR-mode?
Or an link or anything tha would help me to the right path.

Thanks you.

Comment: Well, I'm actually now searching for the same stuff... I don't understand why the trolls at stackovertroll closed your question. How did you solve this?

Comment: @AdrianSalazar Well I do agree this is not a code question rather than a find me a framework question. Anyway, I actually went from the other end and found a js library that supported ECB mode. My case was I had to encrypt in .Net and decrypt in Javascript. If you really want CTR the answers below seems pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Bouncy Castle supports CTR

http://www.bouncycastle.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [NCiphers.Crypto](http://nciphers.com/) library. It supports CTR:

```
NCiphers.Ciphers.AES aes = new NCiphers.Ciphers.AES();
aes.Mode = NCiphers.Ciphers.CipherBlockMode.CTR;
aes.Encrypt...
```

Answer (score -5):

Here's one in JavaScript:
http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html

You could integrate it into your .NET app using [JavaScript.NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Might be a bit slow, but it should be really easy to get it running.

Or, you could use it as a model for building your own implementation.

Comment: I would not advise to do AES in .NET by using a JavaScript implementation. On the other hand, one could use it as a model to build the counter mode from ECB mode.